# How to disable Atom from automatically copying highlighted text

Tags: atom-editor

Atom automatically copies whenever a line of text in my code is being highlighted or blacken out with the mouse hovers without me telling it to do so (by Ctrl-C or choose copy).

I have spend quite a long time researching online to find a way to turn off this feature as I found this feature really irritating but I haven't found anything about it. I would really appreciate it if someone could show me a way to turn this off.

Comment: Atom doesn't do that by default, so it must be a third-party package responsible for this behaviour. The quickest way to verify is to launch Atom in safe mode (`atom --safe`), which skips loading third-party packages.

Comment: Check your packages installed, one of them should be responsible for that (for example `copy-highlighted`). Disable (or uninstall) it.